# Why there isn't a crossbrowser html editor similar to dreamweaver?

Tags: cross-browser, wysiwyg, frontend, html-editor

As far as i know, there are many wysiwyg (what you see is what you get) editors but none of them successful when it comes to crossbrowser issues.

There are few frameworks such as twitter bootstrap, 960.gs, blueprint etc...

Is that so hard to building a crossbrowser wysiwyg editor ?

What are the main barriers behind that ?

I know this is not a trivial but if there is a program or tool like that it will definitively make things much more easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with this are the different rendering engines in the browsers. They of course all try to implement the same HTML/CSS standards, however there is sometimes much room to interpret these standards leading to different results.

Currently the only way to ensure cross-browser compatibility is to use a component which is not rendered by the browser directly, such as a Java applet.

There are some commercial Java based WYSIWYG editors, e.g.:

[edit-on NG](http://www.realobjects.com/products/edit-on-ng/)

[Sferyx](http://www.sferyx.com/htmleditorapplet/)

or edit Live